# How to solve du: cannot access error in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using rsync to transfer files from one server to another.Now i have to check the size of directory and compare size.If size of the directory are same then rsync is successful.I tried doing that but in path i find some error "du: cannot access".Can anyone please tell me how to do that.Thanks in advance.

Below is my code:

```
path = '/mnt/rsyncap/Monte Carlo'
size_cmd = 'ssh -l root -A '+ rh +' -i /Users/macbookpro/Development/serverkey/id_rsa  du -sh %s' % path
Size = subprocess.Popen(size_cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,shell= True).communicate()[0]
```

In the above code you can see the path.In that there is a space between "Monte Carlo" just because of that it shows and error in du -sh line.So how to handle space between directory name and get the size.If there is no space in directory name then it works properly.

Output:

```
du: cannot access `/mnt/rsyncap/Monte': No such file or directory
du: cannot access `Carlo': No such file or directory
```

So please help me if anyone have any idea about this.

Answer (score 1):

[Pass a list of arguments](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen), not a string, and escape your path properly.

```
import shlex

size_cmd = [
    'ssh', '-l', 'root', '-A', rh,
    '-i', '/Users/macbookpro/Development/serverkey/id_rsa',
    'du -sh %s' % shlex.quote(path),
]
```

Comment: Hello, I tried doing this but still there is an error.                                          'du -sh %s' % shlex.quote(path),
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'quote'

Comment: @AnujPhophalia: Which version of Python are you using? If it’s earlier than 3.3, `import pipes` and use `pipes.quote` instead.

Comment: hi , i am using python 2.7.6 version. Even i tried using pipes.quote but output is  usage: ssh [-1246AaCfgKkMNnqsTtVvXxYy] [-b bind_address] [-c cipher_spec]
           [-D [bind_address:]port] [-e escape_char] [-F configfile]
           [-I pkcs11] [-i identity_file]
           [-L [bind_address:]port:host:hostport]
           [-l login_name] [-m mac_spec] [-O ctl_cmd] [-o option] [-p port]
           [-R [bind_address:]port:host:hostport] [-S ctl_path]
           [-W host:port] [-w local_tun[:remote_tun]]
           [user@]hostname [command]

Comment: @AnujPhophalia: You don’t appear to have specified a hostname to connect to. If you took it out for the question, add it back as a single list element before `'du -sh %s…`.

Answer (score 0):

just try, `path = '/mnt/rsyncap/Monte\ Carlo'`.

Comment: By the way, I strongly recommend you not to add any space in the path.

Comment: hi, i tried but its not working. Any other solution.

Comment: ```path = '"/mnt/rsyncap/Monte\ Carlo"'``` different linux commands have different solution to avoid the space ambiguity